# AlertDialog and with list items and custom theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I can't find the solution! I am trying to be compliant with Android 2.1 and later.

I try to create an equivalent to AlertDialog with a a custom theme.

I found that it is not possible to apply a theme on an AlertDialog before API v. 11. And I try to use ContextThemeWrapper, but I can't find a solution to customize the buttons.

For a simple view, I create my own Dialog with my own content view. And I do what I want with the theme.

But, when I want an AlertDialog with a custom theme AND a list item, it is more complicated. I can't find a solution to add button at the end of the list. Because when the list is too big, the buttons are outside the window.

I tried with :
- a RelativeLayout :
    * Title
    * ListView below title
    * Buttons below ListView
- A LinearLayout vertical

Anyone has an idea ?

I add the [result needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOH9R.png).

Maybe, my last, and very ugly idea, is to create a normal AlertDialog with a builder, find each view with findViewById and apply the desired theme attributes... but I have to see if the ids are constant since Android 2.1 ...

My layout xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.levelup.beautifulwidgets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_background"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_1"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            style="@style/DialogButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            style="@style/DialogButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should be doable with a RelativeLayout, can you post the code that you tried? maybe we can help you get it working.

Comment: I just add the xml file.

Comment: I found a solution.

I an vertical LinearLayout.
All the view are with a layout_weight to 0.
Just the ListView is 1.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out can you post the code that you ended up using as an answer and accept it once it will let you. That way if anyone has the same problem in the future it will be easy for them to find this page and figure out how they can accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I an vertical LinearLayout. All the view are with a layout_weight to 0. Just the ListView is 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/Dialog.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/title_container" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_header_divider" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/grey_2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            style="@style/Dialog.Button.Cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/buttonSeparator"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/grey_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            style="@style/Dialog.Button.Ok"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```